# How do I add a google maps marker when Pressing a button?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to fetch all child nodes from parent in firebase db?

Trying to say this: [image: this]

I want to get all posts at the same time.

It fetches videos but only the current users videos. I want to fetch ALL users videos at the same time. 
Here's some code to get more understanding of what I'm doing:

```
fileprivate func fetchAllPost() {
    fetchPosts()
    fetchAllPostsFromUserIds()
}

fileprivate func fetchAllPostsFromUserIds() {
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else { return }
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let userIdsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        userIdsDictionary.forEach({ (key,  value) in
            FIRDatabase.fetchUserWithUid(uid: key, completion: { (user) in
                self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
            })
        })
    }) { (err) in
        print("failed to fetch following users ids:", err)
    }
}

var posts = [Post]()
fileprivate func fetchPosts() {
    guard let currentUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else { return }
    FIRDatabase.fetchUserWithUid(uid: currentUserID) { (user) in
        self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
    }
}

fileprivate func fetchPostsWithUser(user: User) {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts/\(user.uid)/")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        dictionaries.forEach({ (key,value) in

            guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            var  post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)
            post.id = key
            guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else { return }
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("likes").child(key).child(uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let value = snapshot.value as? Int, value == 1 {
                    post.hasLiked = true
                } else {
                    post.hasLiked = false
                }
                self.posts.append(post)

                self.posts.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                    return p1.creationDate.compare(p2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
                })
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

            }, withCancel: { (err) in
                print("Failed to fetch info for post")
            })
            print(self.posts)
        })
    }) { (error) in
        print("Failed to fetch posts", error)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Swift, but you could fetch `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")` and then iterate over [`children`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#children).

Comment: Yeah that will iterate over the users ids. But not the posts inside in the user id

Comment: Use `children` in the child snapshot